# $V/\ker T$ is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be Banach spaces.

Let $T:V\to W$ be a surjective bounded linear map.

I would like to prove that $V/\ker T$(the topology is given by the quotient topology) is a Banach space. In order to prove that, I only need to prove $\ker T$ is a closed subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ker T$ is closed because $T$ is continuous and $\ker T$ is the preimage of the zero point.

Comment: $T$ is not linear map between finite dimensional vector space, but why continuous?

Comment: @Nekojiru because bounded

Comment: @Nekojiru I’m surprised if you’re not familiar with the fact that for a linear map boundedness is equivalent to continuity.